# Django - Add reverse foreign key in values list

Tags: django

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

class MyRelatedModel(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    myModel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

what I'd like is to include the related objects of each MyModel in the list of values

```
myModels = MyModel.objects.all()

data = list(myModels.values('name','MyRelatedModel__name') #off course, this does not work
```

output needed (something like):

```
[{'name': 'MyModel_1', 'myRelatedModel': [{'name': 'myRelatedModel1'}, {'name': 'myReladedModel2'}]}]
```

is there a way to do that? maybe by iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible:

```
output = [{'name': mymodel.name, 
           'myRelatedModel': [{'name': related_model.name} for related_model in mymodel.myrelatedmodel_set.all()]} 
          for mymodel in MyModel.objects.all()}]
```

Comment: this is not efficient way to do it . Is there any other alternative ??

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can get this like:

```
myModels = MyModel.objects.all()

data = list(myModels.values('name','myrelatedmodel__name'))
```

An easier solution could be:

```
data = MyModel.objects.values('name','myrelatedmodel__name')
```

Comment: Thats interesting, but instances of MyModel are duplicated for each MyRelatedModel related instead of putting the related into a list